# Differences between user created structs and framework structs in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, struct, value-type

Why C# compiler does not allow you to compile this:

```
int a;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

but does allow you to compile:

```
MyStruct a;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

where MyStruct is defined as:

```
struct MyStruct
{

}
```

Update: in the firsts case the error is:

> Error 1   Use of unassigned local
>   variable 'a'

Comment: Neither example compiles for me (.NET 3.5). Also, 'int a;' does not declare a struct.

Comment: @Anna: Are you claiming that `int`/`Int32` isn't a struct?

Comment: it's a shame we have to guess for the error message.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I've amended my question with the error message.

Comment: @LukeH: I didn't think it was, but I stand corrected. Learned something today. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# does not allow reading from uninitialized locals.  Here's an extract from [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E) that applies in this context:

> 5.3 Definite assignment
>
> ...
>
> A struct-type variable is considered
> definitely assigned **if each of its
> instance variables is considered
> definitely assigned.**

---

Clearly, since your struct has no fields, this isn't an issue; it is considered definitely assigned. Adding a field to it should break the build.

On a somewhat related note:

> 11.3.8 Constructors
>
> No instance member function can be called until all fields
> of the struct being constructed have
> been definitely assigned.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because an `int` local variable (unlike an `int` as a class or struct member) has no default value.  The `struct` output in your example only works because it has no members.

Default values discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

This would work:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int c;
}

int a = new int();
MyStruct b = new MyStruct();

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler simply doesn't like the fact that your integer is used before being initialized.

```
Error   5   Use of unassigned local variable 'a'
```